# Meaning of "nur" in "nur fünf Jahre alt geworden"

Tags: adverb

> Er ist nur fünf Jahre alt geworden.

Can it mean

(a) He only just became five years old.

(b) He lived only to five years old (and died).

or both?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Definitely (b) and (b) only. To express (a) in German, you'd use something like

> Er ist gerade erst fünf geworden. (He only just turned five.)
>
> Er is gerade mal fünf Jahre alt. (He's only five years old).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe as a little add to the existing answer, it would be helpful to pinpoint where does this confusion arise.

In English you use the adverb *only, just, ...* (or it's synonims) to narrow a quantity, a situation, etc. When these turn out to be of temporal character, one no longer uses *nur* but *erst*, or *gerade erst*, as in teylyn's answer.

Comment: careful there... "Ich kann morgen nur um 8"... temporal use of "nur". "Ich habe erst 3 Euro." ... non-temporal use of "erst". So the distinction between "nur" and "erst" has nothing to do with time. As a matter of fact "erst" tells us something about the speakers opinion, while "nur" simply measures... I have discussed "erst" in detail on my blig: http://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com/2012/06/25/erst-meaning/